# How to Index String with XML or JSON in Solr without using SolrInputDocument

Tags: java, json, xml, scala, solr

I need to index a Collection of Strings in Solr.

Each String contains XML content, similar to the one below:

```
<item>
  <property>"Test"</property>
  <property2>"Test"</property2>
  <property_nested>
    <nested1>"Nested"</nested1>
    <nested2>"Nested"</nested2>
    <nested3>"Nested"</nested3>
    <more_nested>
      <prop>"testing"</prop>
      <prop2>"testingTotalAmount"</prop2>
      <prop3>"one more property"</prop3>   
    </more_nested>
  </property_nested>
</item>
```

My code is something similar to this:

```
List<String> xmls = allXML();
xmls.foreach(x -> {
    // INDEX using solrClient
});
```

For each element in my collection I should get a corresponding document in Solr. Respecting the Schema of it, with nested tags, etc, the types can be inferred.

SolrJ gives me the class: 
`org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument`

Although this class allows me to add fields, properties and then index my data. I find it redundant to use it, and it will make me write a lot of code to extract tag values and put them into the SolrInputDocument. I'd rather have an alternative and just index the data String I have in Solr right away.

**How can I index each element string in my collection in Solr, preserving its schema, or in other words its nested tags, without using SolrInputDocument?**

> I am also considering using Scala, instead of Java, but did not find
>   any library so far.
>
> And I am also considering Json MimeType, as long as the requirements can be kept

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index each element in your input XML then I believe you will have to extract those values in put under different Solr fields.

> it will make me write alot of code to extract tag values

Regarding this, using XSLT would help you transform the input XML into Solr XML document format.

-Amit

Comment: Isn't Solr just able to infer the Schema? I thgout if I gave an XML file to index in Solr under an Index, the Schema would be inferred from the document itself, just like in Elasticsearch

Comment: You could try it out. I have used JSON in a schemaless Solr successfully. However I do not think that applies to XML. Please refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode

Comment: As far as I know it works for XMl as well, I have sucessfully done it, from SOlr Scripting, not from a Java Code, I need to do it using SolrJ

Comment: SolrJ is java API for solr so I am confused by your comment.

Comment: I need to use SOlrJ to index those XML Strings in Solr, but I only found SolrInputDocument, which seems not very convenient for my use case.